# Bootstrap Navbar-fixed-bottom div overlaps JS rendered content

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

The content that generates in my main page container is overlapped by the content of this DIV:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-bottom"></div>
```

Here is the CSS from the github project (bootstrap sass)

```
// Fix the top/bottom navbars when screen real estate supports it
.navbar-fixed-top,
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  border-width: 0 0 1px;

  // Undo the rounded corners
  @media (min-width: $grid-float-breakpoint) {
    border-radius: 0;
  }
}
.navbar-fixed-top {
  z-index: $zindex-navbar-fixed;
  top: 0;
}
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0; // override .navbar defaults
}
```

I belive this is occuring due to JS rendered content rendering after the page is loaded.

Is there any way to fix this without knowing the vertical height of the JS content ahead of time?

**EDIT**

Here is the CSS for the container DIV above the navbar:

```
-webkit-animation-delay: 0s;
-webkit-animation-direction: normal;
-webkit-animation-duration: 0s;
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: none;
-webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
-webkit-animation-name: none;
-webkit-animation-play-state: running;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-app-region: no-drag;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
-webkit-background-clip: border-box;
-webkit-background-composite: source-over;
-webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
-webkit-background-size: auto;
-webkit-border-fit: border;
-webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px;
-webkit-border-image: none;
-webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px;
-webkit-box-align: stretch;
-webkit-box-decoration-break: slice;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-box-flex: 0;
-webkit-box-flex-group: 1;
-webkit-box-lines: single;
-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
-webkit-box-pack: start;
-webkit-box-reflect: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-clip-path: none;
-webkit-column-axis: auto;
-webkit-column-break-after: auto;
-webkit-column-break-before: auto;
-webkit-column-break-inside: auto;
-webkit-column-count: auto;
-webkit-column-gap: normal;
-webkit-column-progression: normal;
-webkit-column-rule-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
-webkit-column-rule-style: none;
-webkit-column-rule-width: 0px;
-webkit-column-span: none;
-webkit-column-width: auto;
-webkit-filter: none;
-webkit-font-kerning: auto;
-webkit-font-smoothing: auto;
-webkit-font-variant-ligatures: normal;
-webkit-highlight: none;
-webkit-hyphenate-character: auto;
-webkit-hyphenate-limit-after: auto;
-webkit-hyphenate-limit-before: auto;
-webkit-hyphenate-limit-lines: no-limit;
-webkit-hyphens: manual;
-webkit-line-align: none;
-webkit-line-box-contain: block inline replaced;
-webkit-line-break: auto;
-webkit-line-clamp: none;
-webkit-line-grid: none;
-webkit-line-snap: none;
-webkit-locale: auto;
-webkit-margin-after-collapse: collapse;
-webkit-margin-before-collapse: collapse;
-webkit-marquee-direction: auto;
-webkit-marquee-increment: 6px;
-webkit-marquee-repetition: infinite;
-webkit-marquee-style: scroll;
-webkit-mask-box-image: none;
-webkit-mask-box-image-outset: 0px;
-webkit-mask-box-image-repeat: stretch;
-webkit-mask-box-image-slice: 0 fill;
-webkit-mask-box-image-source: none;
-webkit-mask-box-image-width: auto;
-webkit-mask-clip: border-box;
-webkit-mask-composite: source-over;
-webkit-mask-image: none;
-webkit-mask-origin: border-box;
-webkit-mask-position: 0% 0%;
-webkit-mask-repeat: repeat;
-webkit-mask-size: auto;
-webkit-perspective: none;
-webkit-perspective-origin: 585px 196px;
-webkit-print-color-adjust: economy;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
-webkit-svg-shadow: none;
-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.180392);
-webkit-text-combine: none;
-webkit-text-decorations-in-effect: none;
-webkit-text-emphasis-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
-webkit-text-emphasis-position: over;
-webkit-text-emphasis-style: none;
-webkit-text-fill-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
-webkit-text-orientation: vertical-right;
-webkit-text-security: none;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;
-webkit-transform: none;
-webkit-transform-origin: 585px 196px;
-webkit-transform-style: flat;
-webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
-webkit-transition-duration: 0s;
-webkit-transition-property: all;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: ease;
-webkit-user-drag: auto;
-webkit-user-modify: read-only;
-webkit-user-select: text;
-webkit-writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
align-content: stretch;
align-items: stretch;
align-self: stretch;
alignment-baseline: auto;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
background-image: none;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-position: 0% 0%;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-size: auto;
baseline-shift: baseline;
border-bottom-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-collapse: separate;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
border-left-style: none;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
border-right-style: none;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-top-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
border-top-left-radius: 0px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-style: none;
border-top-width: 0px;
bottom: auto;
box-shadow: none;
box-sizing: content-box;
buffered-rendering: auto;
caption-side: top;
clear: none;
clip: auto;
clip-path: none;
clip-rule: nonzero;
color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
color-interpolation: srgb;
color-interpolation-filters: linearrgb;
color-rendering: auto;
cursor: auto;
direction: ltr;
display: block;
dominant-baseline: auto;
empty-cells: show;
fill: #000000;
fill-opacity: 1;
fill-rule: nonzero;
filter: none;
flex-basis: auto;
flex-direction: row;
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
float: none;
flood-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
flood-opacity: 1;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
font-size: 14px;
font-style: normal;
font-variant: normal;
font-weight: normal;
glyph-orientation-horizontal: 0deg;
glyph-orientation-vertical: auto;
height: 392px;
image-rendering: auto;
justify-content: flex-start;
kerning: 0;
left: auto;
letter-spacing: normal;
lighting-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
line-height: 20px;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-position: outside;
list-style-type: disc;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 367.5px;
margin-right: 367.5px;
margin-top: 0px;
marker-end: none;
marker-mid: none;
marker-start: none;
mask: none;
mask-type: luminance;
max-height: none;
max-width: none;
min-height: 0px;
min-width: 0px;
opacity: 1;
order: 0;
orphans: auto;
outline-color: rgb(51, 51, 51);
outline-offset: 0px;
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
overflow-wrap: normal;
overflow-x: visible;
overflow-y: visible;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
page-break-after: auto;
page-break-before: auto;
page-break-inside: auto;
pointer-events: auto;
position: static;
resize: none;
right: auto;
shape-rendering: auto;
speak: normal;
stop-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
stop-opacity: 1;
stroke: none;
stroke-dasharray: none;
stroke-dashoffset: 0;
stroke-linecap: butt;
stroke-linejoin: miter;
stroke-miterlimit: 4;
stroke-opacity: 1;
stroke-width: 1;
tab-size: 8;
table-layout: auto;
text-align: start;
text-anchor: start;
text-decoration: none;
text-indent: 0px;
text-overflow: clip;
text-rendering: auto;
text-shadow: none;
text-transform: none;
top: auto;
transition-delay: 0s;
transition-duration: 0s;
transition-property: all;
transition-timing-function: ease;
unicode-bidi: normal;
vector-effect: none;
vertical-align: baseline;
visibility: visible;
white-space: normal;
widows: auto;
width: 1170px;
word-break: normal;
word-spacing: 0px;
word-wrap: normal;
writing-mode: lr-tb;
z-index: auto;
zoom: 1;
```

Comment: What `z-index` values are being applied?

Comment: Well, I mean, wouldn't changing them just cause content to overlap my fixed footer?

Comment: For Pete Sake's sake, show us some code already. More HTML + CSS.

Comment: We don't need to see `Computed Style` from the Chrome DevTools. The CSS from your 'generated content', though, we do need.

Comment: Scroll down to the bottom, it's all there

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The default z-index for fixed navbars is 1030, as such it will appear above most content at the bottom of your screen.

You can try adding the following CSS as suggested in the bootstrap documentation:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-fixed-bottom

```
body { padding-bottom: 70px; }
```

Unfortunately, if you have enough content that scrolling is required, it will still appear behind the menu until you reach the bottom of the page. Once you're at the bottom of the page, the padding you've added to the body should push the content above the navbar, which has a default height of 50px.

Edit:
If you want it at the bottom but no floating, you'll have to render the navbar last in your HTML.

```
<body>
  <div class="container><!-- Content --></div>
  <footer><!-- Footer Content --></footer>
  <div class="navbar navbar-default" style="margin-bottom:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;clear:both;"><!-- Navbar Code --></div>
</body>
```

The problem with this is that without enough content, the navbar can appear above the bottom of the browser window, but it will be at the bottom of the content.

There are other CSS hacks that can be used, but they may likely interfere with bootstrap's styles and cause additional rendering problems.

One example I found, but haven't tested with bootstrap: 
http://ryanfait.com/html5-sticky-footer/

Comment: I have NO IDEA how I missed this. Congrats on getting the easiest bounty ever. Facepalm!

Comment: Hey by the way, I saw your homepage, and I'm actually looking for a navbar like the one you've employed.. with one exception.. I want the navbar to always appear at the bottom of the page, even when the body of the page is short (as in your landing page)... I like how it works on your other pages.. NOT FIXED.. but appearing on the bottom

Comment: All you should need to do is change 
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
to
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom">
and then adjust the padding of the body.
You're unfortunately going to have to used a fixed position to get it to align at the bottom due to the way the box models work with HTML. It's very difficult to get a consistent bottom-aligned menu without having it float.

Comment: Oh I mean, on your page, it's not fixed.. As in, it only appears when you scroll to the bottom?

Comment: You could try just using class="navbar navbar-default" and then making sure your navbar is rendered at the bottom of your HTML output. Assign the styles: "bottom: 0; position: relative; width:100%; margin-bottom:0px;"

Comment: I edited the answer to include some adjustments that may work for you given the non-floating requirement.